# Some Product Titles on Woocommerce are Not in Order

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

Please help me.

I'm selling some products in Woocommerce.

I've modified the "sort by" function to make it simple, so it will only sort by price and title. The default sorting is alphabetically (ascending).

But strangely, not all product titles are in order alphabetically. For example, this one:

[image: SCREENSHOT 1]

The "Swe in Black" is supposed to appear before "Tally Ho Fan Back Red", but it appears otherwise.

And this one also:

[image: SCREENSHOT 2]

The last three products are not in order alphabetically. Moreover, there always appears a blank white space before the last product.

Here's my product page link:
cardstory.co/collections

Strange is, **this only happens in some browsers (e.g. Firefox, Chrome)**. But not in Safari.

--

Here's my custom function.php code for product sorting:

```
<?php

// Edit WooCommerce dropdown menu item of shop page//
// Options: menu_order, popularity, rating, date, price, price-desc

function my_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {
    unset($orderby["popularity"]);
    unset($orderby["rating"]);
    unset($orderby["date"]);
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( "woocommerce_catalog_orderby", "my_woocommerce_catalog_orderby", 20 );


//Attach function to filter hook
add_filter('woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

//add new options to $sortby var passed into filter
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby($sortby) {
    $sortby['name_asc'] = "Sort by name: A-Z";
    $sortby['name_desc'] = "Sort by name: Z-A";
    return $sortby;
}


//Attach our function to the filter hook:
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_catalog_ordering_args');

//Function to handle choices
function custom_catalog_ordering_args($args) {
    global $wp_query;
    // Changed the $_SESSION to $_GET
    if ($_GET['orderby'] == "name_asc") {
        $args['orderby'] = 'title';
        $args['order'] = "ASC";
    } else if ($_GET['orderby'] == "name_desc") {
        $args['orderby'] = 'title';
        $args['order'] = "DESC";
    }
    return $args;
}
```

I've disabled all plugins for this page but nothing works.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: Do you have a live link? Do you have any caching happening?

Comment: This is the link to product page: http://cardstory.co/collections @helgatheviking . I think it doesn't have anything to do with the cache (if I'm not mistaken), since my client also experienced the same thing from his side.